# In Brownie test, how to call contract's __default__() method?

Tags: testing, brownie, vyper

I have a contract Foo with a `__default__()` method.  I have another contract Bar that invokes Foo's `__default__()` method when it calls `send(foo.address, 1)`.

When running Brownie tests, with both Foo and Bar deployed, Bar is reverting when it calls `send(foo.address, 1)`.  Unfortunately, I get no useful info about why Bar's send() fails.  Therefore, I want to some how call Foo's `__default__()` directly in my Brownie test.

1. Can a Brownie test invoke a contract's `__default__()` method?
2. If so, how?

What I tried:

- In Brownie test, called a non-existent method on a deployed Foo contract object.  Was hoping the call would be dispatched to Foo's `__default__()` method, but it wasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being new to Ethereum smart contracts, I didn't realize how easy it was to send eth from a *Brownie test* to a deployed contract.  For future newbies, here's how:

```
# deploy contract
myContract = MyContract.deploy({'from': admin})

# transfering from an account to contract calls the contract's __default__() method
accounts[0].transfer(myContract.address, 1)
```